# Dynamically render objects in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, axios, fetch

Given this javascript file:

```
locations: {
"0": {
  name: "Paris",
  lat: "48.866666670",
  lng: "2.333333333",
  color: "default",
  description: "default",
  url: "default"
},
"1": {
  name: "Tokyo",
  lat: "35.666666670",
  lng: "139.750000000",
  color: "default",
  description: "default",
  url: "default"
},
"3": {
  name: "New York",
  lat: "40.71",
  lng: "-74.0059731",
  description: "default",
  color: "default",
  url: "default",
  size: "default"
},
"4": {
  name: "Miami",
  lat: "25.76",
  lng: "-80.19",
  description: "default",
  color: "blue",
  url: "default",
  size: "default"
},
  "5": {
  name: "Los Angeles",
  lat: "34.0522",
  lng: "-118.2437",
  description: "<h5 style='color:blue;font-weight:900;'>Aircraft Carrier:</h5><p>American Airlines</p>",
  color: "blue",
  url: "default",
  size: "default"
},
   "6": {
  name: "Robinson Helicopter R44",
  lat: "25.7090",
  lng: "-80.4381",
  description: "<h5 style='color:blue;font-weight:900;'>Aircraft Carrier:</h5><p style='font-size:.9rem'>American Airlines</p>",
  color: "blue",
  url: "default",
  size: "default"
},
  "7": {
  name: "Robinson Helicopter R44",
  lat: "40.4839361",
  lng: "-3.5679515",
  description: "<h5 style='color:blue;font-weight:900;'>Aircraft Carrier:</h5><p style='font-size:.9rem'>American Airlines</p>",
  color: "blue",
  url: "default",
  size: "default"
},
```

These are city/locations for an interactive map. The JSON for the cities will generate a pin on a map. Right now this is static. Is it possible to Dynamically create these JSON objects with a fetch or axios request coming from a certain endpoint?

So the file at the end should be somthing like:

```
locations: function() {
      fetch('https://www.podhurst.com/wp-json/wp/v2/aviation_map/')
        .then(res=> res.forEach((item,i)=>{
          "${i}": {
          name: "${item.acf.carrier}",
                lat: "${item.acf.latitude}",
                lng: "${item.acf.longitude}",
                color: "default",
                description: "$item.acf.description",
                url: "default"
          } })
         )},
```

Comment: How would you render your childs? by clickin on a parent object and then calling an endpoint with that id (parent)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about render your child objects, but @izambl solution flattens it into an array.

Comment: @EugenSunic So the endpoint will give you all the info like name long & latitude. And the end result would need to be returned like "index": {name: "${fromEndPoint}",lat: "${fromEndPoint}"}

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the inner objects to an array, that way they'll be easier to render

```
const response = {"4": {...}, "5": {...}};

const cities = Object.keys(response).map((city) => response[city]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
fetch('https://www.podhurst.com/wp-json/wp/v2/aviation_map/')
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(res=>console.log({ ...res }))
```

Comment: This received a syntax error: SyntaxError: missing formal parameter

Comment: I'm not sure elaborate

Comment: If you copy and paste that code into a console it will work